# A tense problem about "Before"

Tags: tense

Imagine we are at a beach watching a boat coming, and when it is still far away from the beach, it sinks into the water **without reaching the land**. I want to tell my friend about it. How can I describe the situation? I am confused which tense to use: present or past?

> Example 1:
>
> A: The boat sank into the water before it **reached** the beach.

> Example 2:
>
> A: The boat sank into the water before it **reaches** the beach.

> Example 3:
>
> A: The boat sank into the water before it **was able to reach** the beach.

Comment: 1 and 3 are fine. In 2, the boat sank in the past (past tense *sank*), and it failed to reach the beach before that, so it's failure to reach the beach should also be expressed in the past (past tense *reached*).

Comment: You mean **its failure** (no apostrophe).